# Want to get a simple Bitcoin price quote via Python requests module from Coinbase API

Tags: python, api, coinbase-api

I want to make a simple Bitcoin Price request via Python requests module from Coinbase API

I can get the request to work in Postman hitting this URL:
https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/:BTC-USD/spot
Included two headers:
"api_key":  "xxx",
"a": "BTC"

However the following Python code produces and error:

```
from datetime import datetime
import requests
# Make an API call to Coinbase and store the response
url = 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/:BTC-USD/spot'
headers = {
            'Accept': "*/*",
            "api_key":  "xxx",
            "a": "BTC"
            }
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(f"Status code: {r.status_code}")

# Store API response in a variable.
response_dict = r.json()
print(response_dict)
```

This is the error returned:

```
Status code: 404
{'errors': [{'id': 'not_found', 'message': 'Invalid base currency'}]}
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you,

Comment: Where did you get info about headers and url? It is not even close to what described in [docs](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#get-spot-price).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming what you typed above is your actual code, then the error generated is correct. You have asked for crypto code :BTC and not BTC. Remove the colon and your code should work.